# Efficient depthwise_conv2d for 5D input data with tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using 5D input_data [Batch, Depth, Height, Width, Channel]. I want to do a convolution only along the Width dimension and get an output the same size of the input.

I understood that tf.nn.depthwise_conv2d do that with 4D tensor input [Batch, Height, Width, Channel] but it does not accept 5D input.

I did this method that basically unstack 5D data relatively to the second dimension to get 4d tensor and then stack the results to get back 5D tensor:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
import os
import time    

def custom_depthwise_conv2d(data, kernel, strides, padding):

    size_depth_input = data.shape[1]
    if size_depth_input==1:
        new_strides = list(strides)
        new_strides.remove(1)
        new_data = tf.squeeze(data, axis=1)
        new_kernel = tf.squeeze(kernel, axis=0)
        y = tf.nn.depthwise_conv2d(new_data, new_kernel, strides=new_strides, padding=padding)
        output = tf.expand_dims(y, axis=1)  
        return output  

    else:    
        new_strides = list(strides)
        new_strides.remove(1)

        list_output_convolution_depth = []
        new_kernel = tf.squeeze(kernel, axis=0)
        for id_depth in range(size_depth_input):
            depth_data = data[:,id_depth,:,:,:]
            y = tf.nn.depthwise_conv2d(depth_data, new_kernel, strides=new_strides, padding=padding)
            output = tf.expand_dims(y, axis=1)
            list_output_convolution_depth.append(output)

        output = tf.concat(list_output_convolution_depth, axis=1)

        return output

input_data = tf.ones(shape=(60, 4, 4, 1000, 3), dtype = "float32")
kernel = tf.ones(shape=[1,1,10, 3, 1], dtype = "float32")
output = custom_depthwise_conv2d(input_data, kernel, strides=[1,1,1,1,1], padding="SAME")

print("input_data.shape", input_data.shape)
print("kernel.shape", kernel.shape)
print("output.shape", output.shape)
```

Is there a solution to do it more efficiently/elegantly ?

Comment: I am not certain this is an answer, but tf.keras.layers.Conv3D has a parameter 'groups', described thus: 'A positive integer specifying the number of groups in which the input is split along the channel axis. Each group is convolved separately with filters / groups filters. The output is the concatenation of all the groups results along the channel axis'. Does that not allow depthwise convolution, splitting allong the channel axis? This link says it does https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/53251

Comment: Having posted that previous comment, I realize I'm not 100% sure what you are asking, but still think that approach (Conv3D using 'groups=') combined with a kernel size that is 1 in some dimensions, may give the flexibility you need. e.g. ... kernel_size=(1,1,5), groups=nchannels_in ... should, I think, do a depthwise conv along only the width dimension.